# (ein) flüssiges Deutsch / Englisch usw.

Tags: article

Does the indefinite article make any difference in the phrase *(ein) flüssiges Deutsch / Englisch*?

For example, what is the difference between:

> Sie spricht **ein** flüssiges Deutsch.
>   Sie spricht flüssiges Deutsch.

Or in this example,

> Sie antwortet in **einem** flüssigen Englisch.
>   Sie antwortet in flüssigem Englisch.

Is either version preferred over the other?

Comment: Related: [When to translate “ein” to describe people](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/14912/1224)

Comment: Kann Deutsch flüssig sein? – Ich meine, ist es überhaupt richtig, es als Adjektiv zu verwenden?

Comment: Auch mein Gedanke @Em1. Ich denke `Sie spricht fließend Deutsch` ist geläufiger?!

Comment: @cr0 Das Wortschatz-Portal hat 10 Einträge für "fließend Deutsch", 2 für "flüssiges Deutsch", 2 für "fließendes Deutsch" und keines für "flüssig Deutsch". Zu wenige Gesamtergebnis um repräsentativ zu sein. Google gibt eine klare Tendenz zu "fließend Deutsch" (~472k), gefolgt von "fließendes Deutsch" (~55k), dann "flüssiges Deutsch" (~10k) und zuletzt "flüssig Deutsch" (~3k). Schlussfolgernd "fließend" als Adverb ist die bevorzugte Variante und "flüssig" und "fließend" als Adjektiv werden auch verwendet. – Beantwortet nur nicht meine Frage :p

Comment: @Em1 Wenn es fließen kann, dann muss es ja wohl flüssig sein :)

Comment: Ich würde empfehlen, statt der Sprache das Verb näher zu beschreiben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make a real difference. The meaning of both sentences is nearly the same:

> Sie spricht ein flüssiges Deutsch.
>   Sie spricht flüssiges Deutsch.

A very little difference is that the version with "ein" could have a tendency, that she does it in general, and the second could have a tendency that she speaks fluent at the moment. But in those sentences it doesn't matter at all.

But therefore I prefer a little bit:

> Sie antwortet in flüssigem Englisch.

Answer (score 5):

Eine **Fremdsprache** spricht man **fließend**.

Eine **Fertigkeit** führt man **flüssig** aus, wenn man sie zügig und ohne zu stocken ausführt.

Man kann flüssig schreiben, lesen, häkeln, Bohnen sortieren oder Fußball spielen. "Flüssig" lässt sich von *jeder* Fertigkeit und jedem Ablauf sagen – selbstverständlich auch vom Sprechen. Dabei ist ein grundlegender Unterschied zu beachten:

Wenn man **fließend** spricht, dann spricht man eine *Fremdsprache*. Die eigene Muttersprache kann man nicht fließend sprechen, denn "Muttersprache" ist das Maximum an Sprachfertigkeit, das Ende des Kontinuums, während "fließend" eine der Stufen darunter bezeichnet. Besser als ein Muttersprachler kann man eine Sprache nicht beherrschen, und man kann eine Sprache nicht gleichzeitig auf zwei unterschiedlichen Niveaus beherrschen:

```
Englisch   [x] Muttersprachler
           [ ] fließend
           [ ] Grundkenntnisse
```

Wenn man dagegen **flüssig** spricht, dann spricht man nicht eine Sprache, sondern *man spricht überhaupt*. Wer flüssig spricht, hat eine [Sprachstörung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachst%C3%B6rung) überwunden oder zum ersten Mal Sprechen gelernt – und damit ist [der Gebrauch der Stimme zur Kommunikation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprechen) gemeint, nicht das Beherrschen einer bestimmten Sprache.

```
Nach einigen Wochen Therapie spricht Paul jetzt schon recht flüssig.
```

*"Flüssiges Deutsch" gibt es genauso wenig wie "festes" oder "gasförmiges Deutsch".*

Comment: Laut [Wiktionary-Eintrag zu "flüssig"](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fl%C3%BCssig) ist folgende Definion gekläufig: _[2] Sprache, Stil, Verkehr: in normalem Tempo ablaufend_ - man kann Deutsch folglich _flüssig sprechen_, aber _flüssig_ ist es deswegen noch lange nicht; also: adverbialer Gebrauch in diesem Zusammenhang ja, adjektivischer nein.

Comment: @what I can't agree with your last sentence. According to my research, unlike a nonsense "gasförmiges Deutsch", "flüssiges Deutsch/Englisch usw" seems to be a legitimate and meaningful expression. If you try poking around in Google Books, you can easily find hundreds of examples of this expression.

Comment: @mthomas Ja, natürlich, man kann auch flüssig sprechen. Man kann *alles* flüssig tun. Ich habe meine Antwort mal entsprechend ergänzt, ich hoffe, das ist nun deutlicher.

Comment: @what Actually, "fließend" can be used as an adjective whithout any problem. According to Duden, _[in fließendem Russisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/flieszend)_ is a possible collocation. With "flüssig" and "geläufig" being the synonyms of "fließend", I venture to assume that "in flüssigem / geläufigem Russisch" are perfectly acceptable expressions. Anyway, my quesion was specifically about the _article usage_.

Comment: "Er spricht fließendes Russisch" ist aber falsch. Es geht nur "in fließendem Russisch" oder "fließend Russisch". Und es geht weder "in flüssigem Russisch" noch "flüssiges Russisch", beides ist jedenfalls standardsprachlich nicht möglich, du kannst nur sagen "er spricht flüssig Russisch", was aber nicht dasselbe ist wie fließend Russisch. Fließend bedeutet er weiß sehr viele Wörter und kann auch komplexe Sachverhalte ausdrücken, flüssig Russisch bedeutet, dass er nicht ständig Pausen machen und nachdenken muss, sondern ohne zu stocken spricht (unabhängig davon, auf welchem Kenntnisniveau).

Comment: Meine Antwort ist insofern eine Antwort auf deine Frage, als sie dir erklärt, dass keine der beiden Versionen möglich ist. Zitat: "Flüssiges Deutsch gibt es nicht!" Du fragst, ist A oder B richtig, ich anworte: beide sind falsch!

Comment: I appriciate your opinion and the opinion of the others who commented. I'm going to avoid saying "flüssiges Deutsch". However, this phrase is used by a lot of German-speaking authors in their books. That's why I had to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The indefinite article "ein" should not be used in this context.
If you want to express that someone is talking fluently, do not use the indefinite article in german.

Answer (score 0):

So, as mentioned in another answer, it's correct that–in the real world–there's no difference between using or not using the article.

Also correct is that you should avoid using an adjective.

> Sie spricht (ein) gutes Deutsch.

If there's "gutes Deutsch", is there also "böses Deutsch"?
That's clearly a reason why you shouldn't omit the article if you're going to use the adjective.

However, in my answer I'd like to give another reason why you should add the article.

An absolutely fine sentence is:

> Dein Deutsch ist sehr gut.

In this sentence, we're not talking about German in general, but about the German skills of one particular person. The article is very important. Without article it would imply something like "I like German but don't like English".
So, if the article is of matter here, then it's also of matter in the original sentence. Considering that your German skills are fine and my German skills are fine and someone else's German skills are fine, there must be a 'group of German skills that are fine'. And logically, there's also a 'group of German skills that are not fine'.
So now, if you say that someone speaks "ein gutes Deutsch", you pick one item out of the 'group of German skills that are fine'.
And that's why I opt for using the article if you really want to use an adjective.

Still, it's better using an adverb and you should say: "Sie spricht sehr gut Deutsch".